# alternate row color for dynamic table in c#

Tags: c#

I want to give alternate color to **Rows** which are going to create dynamically. Following is the table structure in **aspx.cs** page, I am using

```
         StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

         foreach (DataRow row in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                html.Append("<tr style='color: Black'>");

                foreach (DataColumn column in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");

            }
            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eee; }
</style>
```

Comment: Good solution, however does not work for IE8, if you still aim to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a counter and incrementing that whilst looping?

Then everytime you output a row and the counter is odd, for example, you can conditionally output a different style for the row.

It may be better to separate the styles as CSS and alternate class names whilst outputting so you don't have to modify your code when/if you want to change the styling of your site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a safe way that works for old browsers.

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
var rowCount = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var className = rowCount++ % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"; //check if it is an odd or even rowCount
    html.Append("<tr style='color: Black' class='"+className+"'>");

    foreach (DataColumn column in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
        html.Append("</td>");
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");
}

//Table end.
html.Append("</table>");
```

Add this CSS for the Rows

```
tr.odd{
    background-color: #999;
}
tr.even{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad practice to mix layout (html) with backend code. And I would suggest you'd solve your problem with a DataRepeater (or Razor depending on your project) in combination with CSS;
-- add a `<table>` first in the StringBuilder btw;

CSS:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

but if you want to stick to this concept you could use a "toggle" boolean, like so:

```
bool background=false;
foreach (DataColumn column in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
if (background) { // add color }
background = !background;
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css`, but if you're looking for pure `C#`, use a counter:

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
var rowIndex = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Rows) {
    html.AppendFormat("<tr style='color: {0}'>", 
        rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? "Black" : "Red"); // Red or anything you want
    foreach (DataColumn column in dsDashboardDetails.Tables[0].Columns) {
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
        html.Append("</td>");
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");
}
//Table end.
html.Append("</table>");
```